# What are the differences between wide partition and data skew in Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

As I understood both are telling data amount in a specific partition should not be more than other partitions. So we should choose proper partition key(s) to compensate for these problems. But really what are the differences between these two idioms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While they can occur for the same reasons (Data Model and Partition Key Cardinality), the data imbalance between nodes can occur for others reasons.

If a partition key is not selective enough, there can be situations where the amount of data partition grows, with a maximum recommended amount of 100 Mb per partition, but ideally not more than even 10 Mb.

While having a low cardinality partition key can result in some skew, you can also get a skew in the allocation of the tokens to the ring. The RandomPartitioner has more of a habit of producing an unbalanced result compared to the MurmurPartitioner - but even Murmur can be improved by using the allocate_tokens_for_keyspace / allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor - the same setting has different names depending on the C* or DSE version being used, but the idea is to provide the partitioner with more information relating to the intended replication factor, so it produces more of a balanced allocation.

A further way in which data can be unbalanced is from the topology choices - if you create a cluster with keyspaces using NetworkTopologyStrategy (recommended that you should), and multiple racks - unless the number of nodes per rack is the same, then the data will not be balanced.
For example (to demonstrate the result, not that you would do this.)

- Rack 1 = 5 nodes
- Rack 2 = 5 nodes
- Rack 3 = 2 nodes.

With an RF of 3 and 100 GB of Data, each rack will hold a replica. Nodes in rack 1 and 2 will roughly be 20Gb each, rack 3 will be 50Gb each (roughly).

This is why the normal advice when using racks is you will increase the node count by 3 per DC as it expands.

Comment: Can I say that Data skew always will cause wide partition? (during time passing)

Comment: Also, can I say that storing a big chunk of data(same as a file, which I know is not a good practice in C*) will cause wide partition even if there is no data skew?

Comment: Wide partitions are a facet of the data model / partition key choice - given skew can occur due to other reasons, you can not directly link them without additional evidence (large partition warnings, low cardinality estimates etc). While storing a large binary is no ideal, it again does not directly cause skew, if the binary data was in a row where the relation of row to partition key is 1-to-1, then unless the binary is very large, the partitions will still be ok.